# Angular success data access globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How do i access success data globally.I have declared  `barChartData` globally and set success data value to `barChartData`.But i can't get it in   `dataSource: barChartData,`

```
var app = angular.module("anglesExample", []);
var barChartData;

app.controller('CitiesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'getReport.php'
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        barChartData = data.collectionSummery;

    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });


}]);


$(window).load(function () {

    $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
        dataSource: barChartData,
        series: {
            argumentField: 'DIVISIONS',
            valueField: 'SUMMERY',
            name: "Collection Summery",
            type: "bar",
            color: '#ffa500',
            label: {
                visible: true,
                connector: {
                    visible: true
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            percentPrecision: 2,
            customizeText: function (value) {
                return value.percentText;
            }
        },

        legend: {
            horizontalAlignment: 'center',
            verticalAlignment: 'bottom'
        }

    });
});
```

How do I solve that? do I need $q promise?

Comment: Can't you put your dxchart in the success function and pass the required data to it?

Comment: @Jai after i set it.Display empty in my output

Comment: Declaration probably is working, you just have a race condition. In most cases dxChart is going to execute before the response to your success callback. @Jai has a good solution to that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems that the **async** behavior of ajax. Actually your code says that put the dxchart when ajax call gets completed, but your page load completes before the ajax call, so you don't have anything in your global var `barChartData`.

You can try doing in a function manner:

```
var app = angular.module("anglesExample", []);
app.controller('CitiesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'getReport.php'
    }).
    success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        makeChart(data.collectionSummery); // pass the data in the func
    }).
    error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
      // error stuff
    });
}]);


function makeChart (data) { // set the data in the args

    $("#chartContainer").dxChart({
        dataSource: data, // use the passed data
        //all the stuff of dxchart
    });
}
```

---

You can create a global function and pass the required data as an argument.

Comment: Why is that declaration doesn't work ? Can you elaborate it ?

Comment: @samitha well that should work actually but seems that global vars are creating issues in your case so i suggested you this. Although you can find out in your browser's console to any js errors if you have.

Comment: @samitha as ajax calls are asynchronous so i think ajax call yet not finished but your page load has finished.